# Can't access my data due to low disk space

Tags: login, users, disk-usage

I was getting low disk space message for the past few days and so I tried to delete unwanted files and transferred many files to my external disk.  My other drives(C: D: E: and F:) have around 10GB free in each.The external disk has about 1TB free space.Still every time I used to log-in the message kept repeating and suddenly one day I was unable to view my data even after logging-in with my user-id due to low disk space and so I cannot access my information in Ubuntu.

The disk usage analyzer shows 4.8GB used/Total 5.1GB .I am unable to figure out how to create space.Once I log-in with my user account nothing is visible on the screen. I am able to log in as a guest, however I can only view my disk partitions but don't have the permission to delete any data or transfer it to an external drive to create space in C:drive. How can I access my data? I am unable to try anything to create space since I cannot even see my files.

Comment: Check /tmp folder , also use find command to search for large unwanted files

Comment: Your description about your system is little bit confusing, whether 10 GB space is left or 4.8 GB. As per your question i am assuming that you have dual boot. Windows and Ubuntu(or some other variant) both.  There may be less space alotted to the ubuntu while installing . This you can check by writing fdisk -l in terminal after logging in  as superuser in terminal. Otherwise you can transfer the files using commands cp to copy or rm to delete the files which you don't need. Keep in mind that using commands in the terminal as su can be dangerous so please read about the command before applying.

Answer (score 0):

Login using tty. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, This will swtich you to the virtual terminal tty1.

Enter your username and password and then try to empty some space from your Ubuntu partition.

You can access your sudo so you can mount your external HDD if it's not so. The mounting point would be at /media so `ls /media` to check whether it's mounted or no.

#### If this doesn't work for some reason

You should use the Ubuntu Live CD, boot from it and choose `try Ubuntu without installing`, once you are in you can mount your partitions and free some storage.